# return ; what does this statement returns?

Tags: c, function, return, printf, undefined-behavior

consider following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( )  
{ 
  int  a ;
  a = message( ) ; 
  printf("--%d",a);
}

message( )  
{ 
  printf("--%d",printf ( "\nViruses are written in C" ));
  return ;
}
```

I am getting output as:(in GCC)

> Viruses are written in c--25--4

My explanation: `return ;` statement returns the value in the Accumulator,the value returned by the latest `printf` is stored in the accumulator...
is this correct or not?

Comment: Your explanation is wrong. There is no "accumulator" in C, nor does the standard allow an empty `return` to return *anything* useful. Compiling with errors on will show it's invalid code, and the effect you get is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Jongware: Substitute "`eax` on Intel 32-bit" for "Accumulator" and add caveats about undefined behaviour, and the explanation is pretty much correct for the compiler the OP is using.

Comment: @RichieHindle: neither `eax` nor "Intel" are part of the C standard (*any* of them, as there are a couple).

Comment: @Jongware: Of course not.  Hence "add caveats about undefined behaviour" and "for the compiler the OP is using".  Just because something isn't in the spec, and shouldn't be relied upon, doesn't mean it can't be explained.

Comment: @RichieHindle I added the `Deep C` slides to my answer which is good for trying to understand these sorts of things from an educational perspective.

Comment: +1 for providing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and explaining what was not clear to you. not sure why this post received two down votes for.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour is undefined.

The reason you're seeing the `4` is that your code happened not to overwrite the register used to return values from functions (eg. `eax` on 32-bit Intel) between the `printf` that prints `--%d` in `message` (which printed the four characters `--25`) and the final `printf` in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by returning nothing from a value returning function though. If we look at the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.8.6.4` *The return statement* says:

> [...] A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a function
>   whose return type is void.

You should really have no expectations on how this should run but you can make some good guesses as [Deep C](http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c) presentation demonstrates in several sections but I would never do any of this in a production environment.

If you had warnings enabled you should have seen several informative messages, for example `gcc` provides the following warnings:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘message’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [enabled by default]
warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void [enabled by default]
```

You are also relying on implicit return types are no longer allowed since C99 but compilers like `gcc` do support them even in C99 mode. So if that is the case then `message` will have an `int` implicit return type.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Deep C slides - very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

It returns nothing. It will terminate your function only. But as your function has no return type in C89 its return type implicitly converted to `int`, but it is not legal in C99 and latter and this will invoke **undefined behavior**.

> If a non-`void` function reaches the end of its body--that is, it fails to execute a `return` statement--**the behavior of the program is undefined if it attempts to use value returned by the function**.

Some compilers will issue a warning:

```
control reaches end of non-void function
```